# PyCharm has failed to load the environment from '/bin/zsh'

Tags: macos, memory, pycharm, segmentation-fault, macos-monterey

I wrote a program about a month ago, and it worked fine. I haven't touched it since than, until today. 
All of a sudden, I get the warning when opening Pycharm: "PyCharm has failed to load the environment from '/bin/zsh'. Integration with tools that rely on environment variables may work incorrectly." I couldn't find a good explanation and solution to this warning, without leaning out of my comfort zone of altering files on my computer. 
When running the program I got the error message "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)". I have read that this error is related to a memory problem or, that a file needs to be closed. 
I have cleaned the memory of my mac so far I know how to and all files are closed. The program reads from one file, but this is only one line, which has worked before and I don´t see how this could cause the error. Otherwise, I did write few other scripts in the same project over the last month, but that shouldn't be a cause of a memory issue, right? 
Restarting Pycharm and my computer didn´t change anything.

The only other thing I can think of is, that I have updated my mac to Monterey version 12.2.1. 
Could that be the cause for this behaviour? Did anyone else have a similar experience after this update? 
And is it possible for the error message and Pycharms warning to be related?

I am thankful for any tip, that may help me understand this behaviour.

Comment: I have also started getting this error today, with no changes to my Mac aside from a reboot.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix this issue through the following steps:

1. Updating PyCharm to the latest version
2. Within PyCharm going to File -> Invalidate Caches -> Checking *all* boxes -> Clicking "Invalidate and Restart"

(Previous attempts to Invalidate Caches with only the default boxes checked did not work for me, but checking all the boxes fixed the issue.)

Comment: No help for me  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

A simple restart of PyCharm worked for me